# Lookup to find a value in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets. Sheet1 has this data

```
Name    red blue
John    x   
John    x   
John        x
John    x   
John    x
```

Sheet2 has this data

```
Name    red blue
John
```

I needed a formula to populate an "x" under columns red and blue since data in Sheet1 has at least one "x" in the red and blue columns. I tried using vlookup/hlookup but it returns the first value. Same with indexmatch.

Comment: What formula did you try and where did you put it?

Answer (score 2):

Use Countifs:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$E2,Sheet1!B:B,"x"),"x","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
IF(COUNTIF(range,"x"),"x","")
```

range would be your column, ex: B2:B99